# Edit Microsoft ChatBot UI design

Tags: css, node.js, azure, bots, botframework

I have setup a QnA Bot via the Azue BotService, and I want to use the WebChat channel, but the default MS Design for the chat interface is quite bland; is there a way for me to edit it?

Is it possible to go form the default theme on the left, so something like Air New Zealand's bot on the right in the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how you want to integrate the webchat in your page but yes it is possible to change the aspect, it's only `css` and `js`

All the details are provided on the GitHub account for the Webchat: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

In a few words:

> Want to run a custom build of WebChat? Clone this repo, alter it, build it, and reference your built botchat.css and botchat.js files.

And for Styling:

> Styling
>
> In the /src/scss/ folder you will find the source files for generating
>   /botchat.css. Run npm run build-css to compile once you've made your
>   changes. For basic branding, change colors.scss to match your color
>   scheme. For advanced styling, change botchat.scss.