# Change the CSS of Chatbot embedded as IFRAME

Tags: botframework

**ISSUE:**

Today my chat bot stopped working and started giving the following error. No changes were made on my end when this started happening.

[image] 
I could not find any error in console log. Then I tested the bot with Emulator and in Azure Portal's Test in Webchat feature and the bot worked fine. This bot is using webchat (iframe embed) as well as DirectLine channel. The DirectLine channel works fine it is only the webchat that is not working.

So to test my theory that I am getting the error because of webchat getting updated by Microsoft. I used the embed code in Azure Portal to use the latest webchat and the webchat channel started working.

**BRIEF HISTORY:**
To modify the UI of the webchat I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510099/change-the-css-of-the-qna-bot-embedded-as-webchat) method to modify the UI of the IFrame of my bot. This method requires to download the source of IFrame, create an HTML page and use that page as a source of your IFRAME in your website (you can see the customization in the image).

Now that I started getting the issue I mentioned above, I tried to do the same thing with the latest version of webchat but it is not working. The webchat is not sending messages and I cannot find what CSS file this new version of webchat is using.

**WHAT I NEED GUIDANCE ON:**

1. Either a way to continue using the old webchat with the proper UI

OR

2. How to update the UI of this new webchat version?

Comment: reason for down vote?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but my question is why don't you just move to using the directline version? There was a recent update to webchat channel which makes it almost unusable. Directline version should be able to give you whatever customization you need.

Comment: I am using directline and webchat to differentiate between two different scenarios. Can you elaborate on the update?

Comment: The latest out of the box version strips out all the formatting and other features like userID caching, mobile responsiveness, etc. I don't know any specifics about it other than that MS appears to be trying to convince users to just use directline webchat for everything. Could you create two separate directline instances to differentiate between your scenarios?

Comment: probably I will have to do that now. Can you point me to documentation/update that shows the new features of latest webchat?

Comment: Sure, I posted some guidance as an answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't advise on fixing the iframe version, but this already wasn't officially supported, and with the latest webchat update Microsoft is moving more to recommending botframework-webchat (directline) to format the UI. A good place to start is the [branding sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/02.branding-styling-and-customization/a.branding-web-chat).

That sample doesn't spell out the options in the code, but if you take a look at the [default options file](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleOptions.js), that should give you everything you need to customize the chat the way you want.

What this does not do is set up the header that used to be present in ootb webchat (and which I see you customized in your example). Now the best way is to do this in html/css, and you probably can just reuse what you did for your custom option. I just created an additional DIV, set it to `height: 40px;`, then set the webchat DIV to `height: calc(100% - 40px);`. Anyone who's good with HTML can probably come up with better than this, essentially you just build your page however you want at that point and the webchat implementation just controls the chat area itself (essentially send box and response/bubble area). I also added a custom button to my header.

```html
<div id="chatbotTitle"><h3 style="padding-left:10px;">OEM CSC Support Bot</h3><button class="btn" id="transcriptButton">Email Transcript</button></div>
<div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Bill for the reply. I am already using direcline and webchat branding by creating style option set. I will probably have to change my approach now and differentiate between the two scenarios using directline somehow

Comment: I tested the bot with ngrok and it works fine locally. I changed the message endpoint under bot settings in azure back to <app URL>/api/messages and I started getting operation returned an invalid status code. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Would need some more information. What part of your code is generating that message? Do you have any further logs either from console or App Insights? Hard to say without knowing where the error is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving is not a web chat issue. It is an issue in your bot that is being reported via web chat because that is the client being used.

Usually, this error is referring to an incoming activity that your bot doesn't know how to handle (i.e. your bot logic). For example, you have a waterfall step in your main dialog that, depending on the user's response, opens a component dialog. That dialog gets user information (name, age, etc.) that, when complete, returns to the main dialog. However, the next step isn't prepared as perhaps the user exited that dialog prematurely or didn't answer all the questions as expected.

Whatever the case may be, because it isn't setup to handle the incoming activity, it isn't returning the dialog's turn status. You will need to debug your code, stepping thru it, to see which "step" is the root cause.

For me, I have experienced this when I set up Web Chat to send an event back to my bot. My bot didn't know what to do with the incoming event-type activity and would produce that error.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can look into this. Event thought this started happening in the middle of the day with a working bot when no change was made to the code

Comment: Does it happen consistently? Are any API calls being made that your bot is dependent on that perhaps are now returning different data? Could a user being attempting to send some attached file (image, etc.) or some bit of text that isn't escaped, caught be regex, or otherwise isn't recognized (an emoji, for instance)?

Comment: none. No API calls. This happened for the first time ever. Funny thing is DirectLine channel works perfectly

Comment: This is happening in webchat v3. If I update to webchat v4 (the latest one) this error disappears. But the only thing holding me is to update the webchat v4 UI to what I have right now.

Comment: Without code, it's going to be near impossible to provide any real help. I think there are several things that should/need to happen. One, you should move away from v3 Web Chat completely. It is deprecated and not supported. If there is an issue that is stemming from v3, it isn't something they will address. If you are unable/unwilling to switch, then I would still advise you step thru your code (both bot and Web Chat) and see what is being sent where, when, and by whom so you have a deeper understanding that will (ideally) lead to a proper solution for you.

Comment: I do not mind moving to v4. Is there a guideline on how to change v4 UI? The way I did for v3 is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510099/change-the-css-of-the-qna-bot-embedded-as-webchat

it is not going to work with v4

Comment: Yes, if you navigate to the [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) repo, you will find that there are plenty of samples demonstrating the various ways you can customize v4 Web Chat. In addition, there have been plenty of answers provided here on SO on related "how-to" questions. Other than elbow grease, you shouldn't have any significant problems.