# How do I modify UI of webchat v4 using Iframe implementation

Tags: botframework

I was using webchat v3 with iframe implementation and used the following to modify the UI of my webchat frame. [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510099/change-the-css-of-the-qna-bot-embedded-as-webchat)

Microsoft released the new webchat v4 but I could not follow the same steps to change the UI in v4 of webchat. Can anyone guide me how to change the UI of webchat v4 with Iframe (not directline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in v4 iframe Web Chat, there is no way to alter the CSS as it is locked down. The only option is to use v4 directline Web Chat.

The iframe version is meant to be minimal, out-of-the-box ready, and purposely designed to not be customized. If you are seeking to customize the UI, then using [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) is what you want.

Does it require a bit of elbow grease? Yes. Is it robust and offer the opportunity to build a better experience for your users? Absolutely.

*Side note: Don't revert back to v3 in order to utilize the iframe and customize. v3 (BotChat) is deprecated and is no longer supported by Microsoft.*

Hope of help!

Comment: Thank you . I have moved to DirectLine!