# QnA Bot css change for beginners

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker, web-chat

I saw a few topics about changing QnA Bot css, but I still do not understand how it is possible to make a changes in style.

I saw this topic:
[Change the Css of the QnA Bot embedded as webchat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510099/change-the-css-of-the-qna-bot-embedded-as-webchat)
And documentation of QnA. They both seem a bit high level for a beginners that just started to use QnA.

I use a simple iframe provided by QnA:

Is there anyone who is willing to help me in understanding how can I make such a change?
I downloaded botchat.css and placed it on FTP. Then i tried to use it in iframe but it did not work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to fully clarify, are you looking to change the CSS of the channel itself, or the CSS of the QnA answers?

Comment: I wanna change a background color of bot itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your issue is simply looking at the components you have. You have a 1) a bot, 2) QnA in the bot and 3) the channel (the iframe, which is webchat). The bot is going to be the conversational logic, and has nothing to do with customization. We can ignore it. The second  part, QnAMaker, is part of the bot logic, one that deals with simple questions and answers. You can customize how those answers look to a limited degree in the QnA portal, such as creating cards, or limited markdown formatting. The third part, webchat/iframe, is what you're looking at for customization.

There is a series of samples, how-tos and READMEs on the botframework-webchat repo that will go in depth on how to make the changes you're looking for.

Link to the webchat repo: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

The old issue you linked in your quewstion is not a valid 'answer', because it's outdated, and BF-Webchat has made many strides in the last 2 years in being able to customize the channel.